# Add new users in jBPM6

Tags: jbpm

I want to add new users in jBPM6 programatically. According to what I found it was possible in jBPM 5. Is that can be done in jBPM6? Please help me, I am very new to jBPM.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create your own implementation of [UserGroupCallback](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/javadocs/org/kie/api/task/UserGroupCallback.html) where you define users, groups, and relations between them. When you set up your RuntimeEnvironment, just pass an instance of your class to RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder. TaskService will then work with the users defined by you.

You can also use some of the [existing implementations](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/identity) from jBPM project which are able to retrieve users from a database or directory server.

Comment: @Ino If this was the answer you can mark this as the answer and upvote it.  I found this useful. +1,  Thanks.